# 2 T-SQL queries that should be the same are not

Tags: t-sql

I have the 2 below queries that should produce the same result as far as I can tell but they are actually producing vastly different numbers. Why is "Between" dates not the same as specifying the month and year of those dates?
What could be causing this?

```
SELECT [Account]
    , SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Account] = 'Specific Account'
AND Month([Date]) = 5
AND Year([Date]) = 2015
GROUP BY [Account]
```

Sum Result: -1,500,000

```
SELECT [Account]
    , SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Account] = 'Specific Account'
AND [Date] BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
GROUP BY [Account]
```

Sum Result: 350,000

I need the first one to be correct because I need to group the results by Month and Year, which would be cumbersome using the second query.

Query that I need ultimately:

```
SELECT [Account]
    , Month([Date]) AS [Month]
    , Year([Date]) AS [Year]
    , SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [Account]
    , Month([Date])
    , Year([Date])
```

Comment: What happens if you change it to `BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-01'`?

Comment: The second query then also produces -1,500,000. Interesting. 
This pointed me in the right direction though. There is inventory adjustment that happens apparently on the last second of the last day of our fiscal year (May 31st). The only date entry with a time value. I thought between was inclusive of the last one. Thanks a bunch! I need to find a way now to exclude that adjustment as both queries now produce the result i don't want.

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought.  You could try `BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31 23:59:59'`, or find some other column that flags an entry as being such an adjustment and exclude them.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. For example, [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) might help if you are using a recent version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 [Date] BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
```

will only include rows on the 31st where the time component is midnight and omit the rest of the day.

You should forget about `BETWEEN` as there is no valid string literal that you can put on the right that will work correctly for `datetime`,`smalldatetime`,`datetime2(0)..datetime2(7)` and use

```
WHERE [Date] >= '2015-05-01' AND [Date] < '2015-06-01'
```

Comment: I'll mark this one as it's the closest to what the issue was. I found the answer in RBarry Young's answer. BETWEEN is not as inclusive as I thought it was. Which makes grouping according to Month and Year a lot harder in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try below for your first case, where you are getting more rows.

```
AND (Month([Date]) = 5 AND Year([Date]) = 2015)
```

instead of

```
AND Month([Date]) = 5 AND Year([Date]) = 2015
```

**==Update==**

I would suggest to use [CONVERT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) function. And you should revise your query like below

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),DATE_COLUMN,112) between '20150501' and '20150531'
```

Comment: `AND`s are associative with each other, so it shouldn't matter.